# How to POST in .Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

i have a login page with Username and Password inputs and also a submit button. I want to call a method in my Controller that checks if the data matches and shows the result. how do i call that method? I tried the following but it didnt work it passes those as parameters

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Logmein", "LoginController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <form method="post">
            <div class="input-group mt-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" asp-for="Userusername">
            </div>

            <div id="login_usernametxt" class="input-group mt-2">

                <input id="login_passwordtxt" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" asp-for="Userpassword">
            </div>

            <button id="login_signinbtn" class="mt-3 btn bg-warning text-light" style="float: right;" formmethod="post">Sign in</button>

        </form>
    }
```

here is my controller.

```
    public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public LoginInfo Logininformation { get; set; }

    
    public IActionResult Userlogin()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Logmein()
    {
        //checks if the data matches.... 
        return RedirectToPage("/Home/Index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyr to include model with following properties Userusername,Userpassword in Logmein() method

**Also u can remove html helper method ( @using (Html.BeginForm("Logmein", "LoginController", FormMethod.Post)))**
Ex:

```
<form method = "post" asp-controller = "Login" asp-action = "Logmein" >
            <div class="input-group mt-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" asp-for="Userusername">
            </div>

            <div id="login_usernametxt" class="input-group mt-2">

                <input id="login_passwordtxt" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" asp-for="Userpassword">
            </div>

          
        <input type = "submit" value = "Login" /> 

        </form>
```

Model Class

```
public class Login
{
   
    public string Userusername { get; set;  }
     public string Userpassword  { get; set;  }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Logmein(LoginModel login)
    {
        //checks if the data matches.... 
        return RedirectToPage("/Home/Index");
    }
```

Comment: thank you it worked. what do i do if i need to call a method that has a parameter? by the way is that [http post] necessary in my controller?